# TFS 2010 - Check which branch was used to publish (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, tfs

We use VS and TFS 2010 to manage code, branch, merge ASP.NET projects.  All the good stuff.  I come from a Subversion background, so some aspects of the TFS process aren't clear to me.

One thing I need to know how to do - work backwards from a published site to the branch/version/label used.  Working outside of TFS, if I navigate via file system to the location that a build was published (on an internal IIS server, for example), I can find the source code as expected.  However, I need to know the branch used to perform the publishing action.

Is there something built-in I can make use of, or is this a build action I would need to introduce myself (for example, paste the branch name into a version file in the root project directory)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TFS, it's the same with any VCS.  *Don't* publish from multiple branches. Either a single "master" or "release" branch, or use a separate branch for each well-defined release.

Comment: How did you publish your application?

Comment: Panagiotis - we will be using a separate branch for each well-defined release.  That is exactly the plan.  However, once you publish from that branch, what then?  When I look at the published location, how would I find the name of the branch used?

Comment: It might be useful to mention how we used to work with SVN - although this was an app built with a different language.  With SVN we would create a tag (essentially a locked branch, if you're not familiar) for each well-defined release.  The deployed application was a working copy which was then switched to the required tag, and then compiled.  Because the deployed area was a working copy, you could query it (via SVN Tortoise, for example) and easily find the full name of the tag used.  Hence you could check the deployed app to find the repo version.

Answer (score 0):

When you queue build, you'll see the server path to the solution `$/teamProject/Project/Project.sln` in the log. The Project name should be the branch name.

Comment: OK, so I could potentially parse the log in a build event to find the server path and then pop it into a text file in the project root.  Then this file (not under version control) could be published along with the rest of the web app.  Thus I could later check the published area for the text file to see the branch name used during publishing.  Does this sound plausible?

Comment: In branch plan, Release branch should be a separate branch, why do you release from multiple branches?

Comment: It's not "release" so much as "publish" from the branches. The objective is - to look at the published location (where the build ends up on the webserver) and have a way of working backwards to the source code version used. So, member of staff could go to any published build on any web server (there may be several builds hosted, different features applied to each), and find the branch/label/changeset version in some way. Then check out that exact version locally to repair or investigate.